# Adding Login View to an App using Tab Bar Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've created a small iphone app that contains a tab bar controller that has been created on the MainWindow.xib. The App Delegate contains the root controller outlet.  I'm wondering how I can work in a login screen that will direct the user to my view controller containing the tab bars.

Current Solution:
On didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add subview "RootController" which loads my MainWindow.xib view with tab bars. Then call "presentModalViewController" to present the LoginViewController as a modal. On the login view controller, the login button click calls the AppDelegate to dismiss the modal.

Does anyone know of a better solution? Possibly a solution that doesn't load the page with tabs until after the user has logged into the app.

Thanks!

Comment: there is another method i use see here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517047/tab-bar-after-login-why-does-it-look-like-this/36517380#36517380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make a separate View Controller (lets say A)
- in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` check if user is logged in .. if not show A..
- implement delegation and pass back login result to the app delegate...and then load the tab bar View

Comment: What do you think about this solution? I'm using a modal to display in front of the RootController(`code`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController= self.rootController;
    LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];  
    
    self.loginController = login;
    [window addSubview:rootController.view];
   
     [self.rootController presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  ..
}

Comment: What do you think about adding the RootController to the window as a subview, then present modal "Login View"? Would it be better to NOT add the RootController as a subview in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" - or is this even possible? If this is possible, I thought about adding the Login View as a subview.