# Tab bar after login - Why does it look like this?

Tags: ios, xcode

so I'm writing this app where I need to have a tab bar after the whole sign up/login part.  I've looked around and I dont see anyone explaining me how to do this or why its happening: when I put the tab bar controller, it appears with no actual buttons, and also how should I connect the app to the tab bat controller? Either way, thats my main question. Am I missing something? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I'm new in IOS Development. I am facing the same issue. can you provide the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have also been developed the application using UITabBarController faced same difficulty how to implement attach login and signup view controller.

by few work around i finally able to achieve that i don't say it is the perfect way but i am using like that,

steps 
make two Stroyboard 
1.login.Stroyboard
[image]

2main.Stroyboard
[image]

3.now on homeviewcontroller.swift which is first tab of uitabbarcontroller

```
        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


          guard (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(USER_INFO) != nil) else {//check user is logged in or not 
           //if user is not logged in present login.storyboard and do the logic there
           let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
           let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController

           target.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
```

4. in loginviewcontroller and signupviewcontroller after sucessfull login or signup dissmiss your login.storyboard

```
       self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in

      }
```

5.here the link of project -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7APKZanPpc3OW92bzQ5QnRXdVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, that is clever. Could I please see your HomeViewController.swift file if you dont mind?

Comment: give your mail id i will give the whole after few hours

Comment: sorry for delay, check your mail now

Comment: hello have you received the mail or should i post the link here